# Stacked bar chart — top X values

Tags: datadog

I wonder if this is possible to achieve in Datadog. I have a data collected under 1 metric `entity.count` - now the data are being posted to Datadog with multiple tags, for example `entity.count.visits`, `entity.count.payment` and probably another 10 different tags.

I'm trying to create Datadog chart in a dashboard, which would display top 5 tags of the entity counts in a stacked bar chart. I know about the option of adding more queries, but since I'm not sure what entities will be available in the future, I would like datadog to always just display dynamically the top 5 entities in the dashboard (Insted of me specifying in the queries what tag to display). This is what I currently have (and it does the job, it's just not dynamic):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible, but you will want to change your tag setup a little. You want to take advantage of `key:value` syntax with your tags, so that you can group out the tags by their common `key`.

So in your case, instead of tagging by `entity.count.payment`, you would want to tag by `entity.count:payment` or better yet `entity:payment`. That way you can write one query of your metric and use the `group by` functionality on the shared `entity` tag key to see it's values for all the different `entity` tags.

From there, you can use the `top` function to always see just the top n values, whether that be `payment` or `cart` or `visit` etc.

[This doc here about tags](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tagging/) is definitely worth a read! Tags can make graphing and monitoring much easier and more scalable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @stephenlechner, I will definitely try out your suggestion!